# Function visibility and access control

Tags: solidity, security

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

function _addStudentAddr(address addr) private onlyOwner {
        students.push(addr);
    }
```

I am creating a smart contract to add frictional students ETH address on-chain ( goerli testnet ), doing this as a personal development project. Now, I am curious if it makes sense to add access modified ( onlyOwner ) to a private function. From a security perspective it is already a private function so I am assuming it is secure, can someone explain more about access modifiers and contract visibility in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general practice, people use access control only on `public` or `external` because these functions can be called by anyone (external accounts, contracts, ...). For `internal` and `private` functions, you don't have to do so because it's only be called by other functions of your own contract and it's redundant if you already have checks on other public functions.
In you code, to access `_addStudentAddr` you have to declare another `public` function and can place access control on that. Without that `public` function, nobody can access `_addStudentAddr` therefore the check for `private` function is redundant:

```
function addStudent(address addr) public onlyOwner {
    _addStudentAddr(addr);
}
function _addStudentAddr(address addr) private {
    students.push(addr);
}
```